# Can I use canvas and form together in a application

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

Can I use Canvas and form together in application? If yes then how can I access form from Canvas?

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and guess you mean a form within a CANVAS element?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use both but not at the same time.  You can switch between them by using [`Display.setCurrent()`](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Display.html#setCurrent%28javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable%29).

Answer (score 1):

You need your Midlet to find its display (and the form).You would to send a reference of your MIDlet to the canvas constructor.So your canvas would be look like this:

```
class myCanvas extends Canvas implements ... {
myMIDlet myHost; // the breadcrumb

    public myCanvas(... , myMIDlet host) {
    myHost = host; // remember our host MIDlet
    ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Where "myMIDlet" is name of your MIDlet.
In your MIDlet:

```
public class myMIDlet extends MIDlet implements ... {
...
Form myForm = new Form( ... 
...
myCanvas ggg = new myCanvas(... , this) // <=== note the last parameter-the key to it all
...   
//switch display to myCanvas
display.setCurrent(ggg);
...
}
```

When you want to got to the form from "myCanvas" (probably in a commandAction or keyPressed methods of your canvas) do this:

```
Display disp = myHost.getDisplay();
disp.setCurrent(myHost.myForm);
```

Reference:
   [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/258727/J2ME-Game-Canvas-Form-switching)

Answer (score 0):

You can switch form to canvas. For example:

```
        canvasName c=new canvasName(this);
        Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(c);
```

But, in Canvas to Form, I don't know.